# Installing Solaris Studio 12.2?

Tags: 10.04, software-installation, package-management, solaris

I'm having a dickens of a time installing Solaris Studio 12.2 on Ubuntu 10.04.  I found [this](http://linuxtree.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-install-sun-studio-12-on.html) guide, however using the alien option isn't finding the correct files.  I'm not exactly sure on the syntax of alien, its kinda alien to me. (sorry for the bad pun)  Also, when I download the tar file, and extract it, there are errors everytime saying things like:

> - "operation not permitted"
> - cannot creat symlink to '../prod/bin/cc': Operation not permitted

I've extracted with super user access, but to no avail. Any success from anyone else?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" could do with some elaboration.  Also, they repackage using alien - it might be a good idea to _start_ with a RPM-based distribution.

Comment: do you have a good recommendation for a RPM base distro?  I'm starting to programm and taking a class... they use SolarisStudio for compiling

Answer (score 3):

Download `SolarisStudio12.2-linux-x86-tar-ML.tar.bz2` (note that this is not the rpm version) for generic Linux from the link given in above post. You also need JDK on your system. Download and extract latest from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.

After extracting the solstudio archive, navigate to that location and run the shell script as root. That will do away with the permission errors.

```
sudo ./[scriptname].sh
```

Next add the sol-studio and jdk bin directories to PATH variable. This can be done permanently by adding the following lines to `/home/[user]/.bashrc` at the end:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/[user]/jdk1.6.0_23/bin:/home/[user]/solstudio/solstudio12.2/bin
export PATH
```

[Replace the paths for jdk and solstudio with those where you extracted them].

Make the bash profile active by running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Once the path is set, run the IDE from terminal normally:

```
solstudio &
```

Some of this info is also available in one of the read-me files extracted along with the main directory.

Answer (score 1):

Download the linux tar binary from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index-jsp-141149.html

(the row "Linux OS on x86", rightmost column)

Then just run the installation script. You can find useful information at:

http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1385/6nmcfgo39?a=view

Comment: That's for a RPM based distro... Ubuntu is Debian and doesn't work with that.

Comment: there is a tar.gz file