# Installing Solaris Studio 12.2

Tags: installation, ide

I need help with installing Solaris Studio 12.2 on Ubuntu.

I looked at this question already and it didn't help: [Installing Solaris Studio 12.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4227/installing-solaris-studio-12-2)

My problem with the solutions provided in that question is that I do not have a script to run when I extract the file I downloaded: `SolarisStudio12.2-linux-x86-tar-ML.tar.bz2`

To extract it I am just using the Ubuntu GUI, archive manager.
Could this be my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from stackoverflow: [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541309/installing-solaris-studio-12-2-in-ubuntu)